# How can I skip the closing quotation mark when typing in the Visual Studio xml editor?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I like that quotation marks are automatically inserted in the Visual Studio xml editor, but I haven't yet found an easy way to get past the second quote without moving my hand over to the cursor keys or hitting End. Is there an easier way to skip past the second quote when the value is a string (Intellisense will skip the quote if the value is an enum)? Might just turn this feature off entirely..

Comment: It's bananas that we're still dealing with this eleven years later.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured this out... hit the `Tab` key.

Comment: Ah sorry, missed "xml editor" the first time. Apparently this only works in a standard class editor, my apologies. And how very frustrating. (I edit xml in notepad++, not that that's useful here...)

Comment: After doing a lot more work in VS/XML/XSD, I think this is by design, since a tab is valid XML string content, and as you say it works on enums. How would VS know your tab was not content? And (as I mistakenly answered already) tab is their convention elsewhere...

Answer (score 1):

ctrl + u should do the job. Not the most magic solution but still the best one available.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `End` Key.

If it works, follow Andrew's advice for creating a macro that's easier to type:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5532162