# Intellisense isn't working with XML Quotation marks - Typing double quotes opens two, and typing double quotes again doesn't move cursor

Tags: xml, visual-studio, intellisense

I'm typing out XML in Visual Studio 2017, and when I type something like `<name id=`, what is printed in the editor is `<name id="|"`, with the cursor in the pipe position.  (It's the equals button that prints out `="|"`

What I expect to happen is when I type double quotes again, `shift-'`, it will move the cursor to the other side of the last double quote: `<name id=""|`.  Instead, it prints another double quote, and leaves the cursor on the left side of the right-most double-quote: `<id=""|"`

If I press tab, it just puts at tab character inside the double quotation marks: `<id="    |"`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260442/how-can-i-skip-the-closing-quotation-mark-when-typing-in-the-visual-studio-xml-e) here remarks that I should be able to shift the cursor outside from the quotation marks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard command to get out of auto generated double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125929/keyboard-command-to-get-out-of-auto-generated-double-quotes)

Comment: Try `ctrl + u`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1125929/1168116

Answer (score 3):

Following your steps, in the XML file and I got the same result as yours, this behavior is by design. I found your expected result can be found in the HTML or CSS file, in the HTML file you need to type double quotes for twice times to move the cursor to the end, in the CSS file, you just need to type double quotes again to move the cursor to display as your expected.

After research, you can have a try with the following:

1. Press End key to move the cursor to the end
2. Disable the auto complete of the double quotes, please go to Tools > Options… > Text Editor > XML > Miscellaneous and uncheck the option “Attribute quotes” as below:
   [image]

Comment: Thanks!  I don't happen to have an end key, so I'll disable the auto-complete as you recommended.